# Jquery function don't get correctly variable

Tags: jquery, function, variables, time

I have a function that is called many times when the window browser is resized or when I click on some elements.

This function calculate the correct width of a container based on children items width (variable colW). It seems that when my function is execute, the colW variable is not correctly get or it's not the right width (it's the previous calculated width).
This colW variable is calculated in function of the window size.

If I put an alert(colW) everything works fine. In this case the variable is correctly get.

I don't know how to resolve this problem. Maybe I didn't correctly set my variable or I need to be sure that the previous fonction is done before to execute the next function.

Here my script:

```
function checkSly() {
    //alert(colW);
    numNormal = $('.element:not(.square,.wide,.tall,.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numSquare = $('.element.square:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numWide = $('.element.wide:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numTall = $('.element.tall:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    totalelement = numNormal+numSquare*4+numWide*2+numTall+3;
    columnswidth = Math.ceil((totalelement)/HIsotopeRows)*colW;
    slideewidth = Math.round(columnswidth);
    $('#container').width(slideewidth);
    frame.reload();
}
```

**EDIT**

if I add a setTimeout, the variable have the time to be calculated (because the colW width animate some elements) and it works great :

```
    function checkSly() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    numNormal = $('.element:not(.square,.wide,.tall,.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numSquare = $('.element.square:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numWide = $('.element.wide:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    numTall = $('.element.tall:not(.isotope-hidden)').length;
    totalelement = numNormal+numSquare*4+numWide*2+numTall+3;
    columnswidth = Math.ceil((totalelement)/HIsotopeRows)*colW;
    slideewidth = Math.round(columnswidth);
    $('#container').width(slideewidth);

    frame.reload();
        }, 300);
}
```

I think I need to wait that all animations are completed before to call checkSly() function...
Is there a way to wait animation are finished before execute a function? Because with setTimeout it will not works all the time (because animation depend on browser type, CPU and others things....)

Sorry for my english, I m french.

Comment: May I ask why you don't just use percentage sizes and media queries like normal people do?

Comment: Because it can't be done like this...

Comment: To have great responsive isotope grid with different items size that the best way for smoothness. But this is not the problem. The colW is correctly calculated. I just want to use it with checkSly() function.

Comment: It would help if your JSFiddle actually worked. Add some HTML to it.

Comment: You seriously need to optimize your code, like chaining jquery methods

Comment: ^ And take all of that repeated stuff and just move it to the end.

Comment: My script for the checkSly() function always get the previous calculated colW variable. There is one step delay...